# What was this sound in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was watching YouTube and this noise came up in one of DanTDM's videos (at 3:44). Does anybody know what it is?

It got me really creeped out. Is it just Dan trying to scare us? Can it happen in my Minecraft worlds?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the cave noises; cave13.ogg and cave17.ogg played at the same time.

Cave noises occur when there's a location with a low light level nearby the player.

Although they sound threatening, cave noises are just atmospheric sounds, they won't harm your player in any way.

As these sounds are purely atmospheric and random, they also don't hint at locations to special certain underground structures, resources, or mobs contrary to some people's beliefs.

However they may hint to nearby dark spaces (usually a cave, but it could be any dark area) underground, as there must be a dark area that's not exposed to the sky for the sounds to occur.

Hopefully this is helpful in explaining the cave noises, and helps to relieve some fear about them.

Edit: I made a mistake in which I thought that Dan was near a cave entrance in that part of the video, which watching it back is definitely not the case, though he's in an mountain biome; which tends to have many near-surface caves, so caves sounds playing where he's at is still a very likely possiblity.

Comment: It reminded me of disc 13 and 11, which makes creepy sounds like this here

Comment: Each of the two individual cave noises are at 1:52-1:56 and 2:23-2:35 of this video of compiled cave noises: https://youtu.be/8aziJ19rq38   if you were to play these two sounds at the same time with a half-second or so of delay, you get a very close sound to the one in the original video.